# How to delete data from String in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, datatables

I have a datatable in which I have checkboxes for each row. Outside my datatable there is a print button which prints the data for selected rows. I am storing all the selected row Ids data by user in a String. Now when user uncheck the checkbox, I want to delete the row Id data from that string object.Whenever user uncheck the checkbox its not deleting the data from the string which I saved earlier. To specify here,I can send only string object to the controller.
I am not sure how to achieve this.

Below is my code.

```
 For print,here is the function
$("img#print").live("click",function(){

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('CheckBoxTest');
var mnFlag = false;
var row;
checkedbills = "";  
for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)
{

     if (checkboxes[i].checked)
     {
        row = checkboxes[i].id;
        row = row.substring(row.search("_") + 1,row.length);
        sData = $("#openItems").dataTable().fnGetData(row);

        if(sData.SrcTypCode == "Y8")
        {
            mnFlag= true;
            checkedbills = invoiceArray;
                }
     }
}
if(mnFlag)
{
        $('#reBill-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 650,
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: "foo1",
            closeOnEscape: false,
            draggable: true,
            canMinimize: true,
            beforeClose: cancelReBill()
        });
        }
    else
     {
         if(billData.length < 1)
         {
        alert("Please select at least one bill to be printed");
    }
         else
         {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: 'data_print',
        data: {billData:billData}, 
        success: function(dataList){
            var printDet = dataList.PrintDetails;
            if(printDet == "N"){
                alert(dataList.PrintMessage);
            }
            else{
                alert(dataList.PrintMessage);
            }

        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         }
    });
}
     }
});
```

Below is the code where I am storing the data in string when checkboxes are checked.

```
                                                                  $('#bills tbody tr   input[name="CheckBoxTest"]').live('change',function(e){
var row=$(this).closest("tr").get(0);
var invsysNumber = $('#bills').dataTable().fnGetData(row).invSysNumber;
var invverNumber = $('#bills').dataTable().fnGetData(row).invVerNumber;
var data = $('#bills').dataTable().fnGetData(row).invSysNumber+','+$('#bills').dataTable().fnGetData(row).invVerNumber;
var index ;
 if(data in checkboxAccIndicator )
    {
    index=1;
    }
else
    {
    index=-1;
    }

if($(this).is(':checked') && (index == -1))
{

    checkboxAccIndicator[$('#bills').dataTable().fnGetData(row).invSysNumber+
                     ","+$('#bills').dataTable().fnGetData(row).invVerNumber]=
    $('#bills').dataTable().fnGetData(row).arLocation;

    if(invoiceArray == ""){
        invoiceArray = "~" + invsysNumber + "," + invverNumber ;
    }else {
        invoiceArray = invoiceArray + "~" + invsysNumber + "," + invverNumber ;
    }


// Otherwise, if checkbox is not checked and row ID is in list of selected row IDs
} 
else if (!($(this).is(':checked')) && (index != -1))
{
   delete checkboxAccIndicator[$('#bills').dataTable().fnGetData(row).invSysNumber+
                         ","+$('#bills').dataTable().fnGetData(row).invVerNumber];

       }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you manage your checkbox ID list as an array then serialize it to a string when you pass it to the controller. This approach is much simpler:

```
// Initialize array
var invoiceArray = [];

// Add item to array
invoiceArray.push(invsysNumber + "," + invverNumber);

// Remove specified item from array
var itemToRemove = invsysNumber + "," + invverNumber;
for (var i=0, il=invoiceArray.length; i<il; i++) {
    if (invoiceArray[i] === itemToRemove) {
        invoiceArray.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}

// Convert array to a string for your controller
var invoiceArrayString = invoiceArray.join('~');
```

Alternately, if you're keeping your current solution where "invoiceArray" is actually a string (poorly named) you would have to convert it to an array anyways to remove an item.

```
// Remove item from "invoiceArray" string
var invoiceArraySplit = invoiceArray.split('~');
var itemToRemove = invsysNumber + "," + invverNumber;
for (var i=0, il=invoiceArraySplit.length; i<il; i++) {
    if (invoiceArraySplit[i] === itemToRemove) {
        invoiceArraySplit.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
// Convert back to string
var invoiceArray = invoiceArraySplit.join('~');
```